# error retrieving youtube videos by channel name in Asp.net MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to retrieve youtube videos by channel name in Asp.net mvc4 web application.I tried googling and tested with all codes I have found but it end up "**Execution of request failed: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/channelname/uploads?orderby=published**"
.Any Help Will Be Appreciated and I am still trying to google it for solution.
Thanks

**Model**

```
public class Youtube
    {
        public string YouTubeMovieID { get; set; }
        public string YouTubeMovieTitle { get; set; }
    }

    public class YouTubeHelper
    {
        const string YT_CHANNEL_NAME = "Heaven Luk";
        const string YT_DEVELOPER_ID = "Devloper ID here";

        public static List<Youtube> GetVideos()
        {
            YouTubeRequestSettings ytSettings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("MyTestingWebsite", YT_DEVELOPER_ID);
            YouTubeRequest ytRequest = new YouTubeRequest(ytSettings);
            string feedURL = String.Format("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{0}/uploads?orderby=published", YT_CHANNEL_NAME);
            Feed<Video> videoFeed = ytRequest.Get<Video>(new Uri(feedURL));

            return (from video in videoFeed.Entries
                    select new Youtube() { YouTubeMovieID = video.VideoId, YouTubeMovieTitle = video.Title }).ToList();
        }
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<MyTestingProject.Models.YouTubeHelper>
@{

    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Foundation.cshtml";
}

@foreach (var v in Model)
{
<object width="427" height="258">
           <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/@v.YouTubeMovieID" />
           <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
           <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>
           <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
           <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/@v.YouTubeMovieID"
              type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="427"
              height="258" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"
              wmode="opaque"></embed>  </object>

}
```

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Videos()
        {
            var videos = YouTubeHelper.GetVideos();
            return View(videos);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The V2 YouTube API has been deprecated. You should be using V3 instead. If you want to get a channel's uploaded videos, you'd have to provide either the channel name or ID, get the uploads playlist, then get the videos from that playlist. Please see the code samples [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet). Alternatively, you could [search](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#examples) for a given channel's videos by specifying the channel ID and setting `type=video`.